# Red line error with correct code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWOgr.png)

Well i have this problem when the code is correct, but it gives me red line error!
can anybody help me.

Main.java

```
package com.example.sout;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import
      ~
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource (R.anim.animation);
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener());
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~
}
```

in (note the `~` characters above):

```
iv.setBackgroundResource (R.anim.animation);
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener());
```

The `setBackgroundResource` and `setOnClickListener` are red too.

Comment: and where is your code? what error do you get? post this in your question and don't link images for that

Comment: Instead of posting the screenshot of your code, do post the code itself.

Comment: If you hover over the red underlined code, what error message do you get?

Comment: cannot resolve sympol ..

Comment: Fix that empty import first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in   `iv.setBackgroundResource (R.anim.animation);` comes because that method takes integer as a parameter .So change it to the following,

```
  iv.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.image1); //image1 is a drawable which is inside your drawable folder.
```

and the second error comes because you have not imported the required package and have not overridden the methods required for that. Change it to the following,

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do your task here
            }
        });
```

after changing press ctrl+shift+p to import the required packages.

Comment: anim.xml contains the  animation-list !

Comment: Dude you can't use animated imaged as ImageView background.You have to use animation for that.

Comment: yes , i put the sequence images of animation .. in drawble file .. then i created anim.xml and i made <animation-list/>

Comment: See this tutorial for xml animations.You will get a nice idea. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, at least with Eclipse, it gets it into it head that there's an error and it won't let it go. But, with Eclipse, you can at least put the cursor over a marker and it will explain what the problem is (or what it *thinks* it is). I'd try to hover over the errant lines to see if a popup box appears telling you what it thinks.

If you're sure it's wrong, often I've found that saving the file (or all files) will fix it. Sometimes adding then deleting a space on the errant line will fix it.

However, I notice that you have an incomplete `import` at the top of your file and this may be preventing the syntax checker from properly analysing the source file.

My advice is to fix that first, then try those other two tricks (save then, if that doesn't work, edit and undo on the errant line). Hopefully that will make it disappear.

Of course, you may want to check, just in case, your `R.java` file to ensure that member exists in there somewhere. I've been bitten by my own misspellings before.

Comment: as a rule of thumb: "always fix errors from top to bottom". Because often you fix one little thing and many errors go away.